# Where have all the scrollbars gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, revision-history, 10k-tools

For some reason, scrollbars at least in the revision history and in the 10k NATO tool aren't present in code blocks, and cause obnoxious effects [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64844524/revisions):

> [image: image showing how the visuals of the website span significantly outside its intended size in the revision history of a question]

... or in the 10k NATO tool:

> [image: same as the first image, but in the 10k NATO tool]

Not sure where else this can be reproduced, but code blocks without scrollbars break the site's design when the code blocks get long enough.

Comment: they need `table-layout:fixed` on `#revisions table`

Comment: Also broken in the revision histories sometimes. See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64941222/revisions).

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65053815/revisions)

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65495883/revisions) (this one is for a question rather than a 10K tool).

Comment: (from the title) ... long time scrolling.

Comment: [Another Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65969701/revisions)

Comment: Is there any progress on this? This is a real pain during editing, and FWIW the editing experience is not the best anyway.

Comment: @halfer not aside [status-perpetual-review].

Comment: I really hope this gets fixed soon. The revisions view of some posts gets [comically wide!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66319823/revisions)

Comment: Let's hope the status-review ticket smash gets it somewhere :')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### This issue is now resolved

[Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel)♦ has posted [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361474/348196) on Meta Stack Exchange announcing the fix:

> I decided to go big here and just make the whole page responsive, replacing the table with carefully calculated header rows that collapse in a reasonable but Designed-by-a-Developer™ way.

Comment: Another time, please raise a custom moderator flag on the question asking for the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag to be added to the question. There isn't a guarantee that a moderator sees an answer saying that the tag should be there, so without a flag it may not happen.

Comment: It's actually not entirely status-complete - the NATO tool is still acting weird. Left a comment on the MSE answer as well